# Lauterbach Trace32 - stack overflow issue when generating functions statistics

Tags: trace32, lauterbach

I'm getting the stack overflow error on the Lauterbach trace statistics for functions.
Suspecting this might be due to too many functions calls.
Anyone has any ideas on how to resolve this?

- Suggestions on how to trace only the needed functions are welcomed as well :)
- Trace file is streamed on USB3, saved locally and then loaded.
- PRACTICE command to generate statistics window: `Trace.STATistic.Func TotalRatio Total MIN MAX AVeRage Count InternalRatio TotalBAR /Sort TotalRatio`
- Tracer: "POWERTRACE 3", Debugger: "POWER DEBUG PRO"
- Image below is a screenshot from the statistics Lauterbach window:
  [Lauterbach Trace32 functions statistics - stack overflow message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AVaVq.png)

Comment: Sometimes it is necessary to use the command [sYmbol.MARKER.Create](https://www2.lauterbach.com/pdf/general_ref_s.pdf#M8.newlink.EMUYMARKERC) for adding a set of markers to help decoding the function/task transitions.It would make sense to get in touch with Lauterbach support directly. This sounds like a straightforward case for them.

Comment: Yeah it looks like LB wont recognize function end/return.
Thanks for the info

Comment: I've been having this issue as well and it looked like LB not recognizing the return like you said.  If you find a solution please share in an answer.

Comment: Did you end up getting this figured out?  I figured out a similar issue on my own setup, the RTOS we are using doesnt play nicely with the lauterbach, it gets confused regarding function enter/exits when the task switch occurs.